# Is there a way to hide/remove the drop box folder (not dropbox.com) that is inside of public folder?

Tags: macos, folders

Inside Public folder there is a folder called "Drop Box" (I'm not talking about dropbox.com) which is used for network/sharing purpose. Since I only use the machine locally, I would like to delete that folder, but doesn't matter how many time you delete or hide it, it keeps appear again.

Any tip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide it from from Finder by setting the hidden flag with Terminal

```
chflags hidden /path/to/folder/
```

and if you want to remove the flag

```
chflags nohidden /path/to/folder/
```

Comment: That's the right answer. Just as some added info, if want to see hidden folders/files in Finder, go to Terminal and enter `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` and `killall Finder`. To hide them again: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE` and `killall Finder` again.